# Debugging QT symbols with CLion

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, clion

## Question

How does one get a debug view of properties of QT items? I'm currently using CLion.

For example, the application uses a QModelIndex.

[image]

I've gathered from [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) that QModelIndex is used in combination with an AbstractItemModel. It seems like the property `m` is supposed to be a pointer to that model. How do I view the data associated with this QModelIndex and/or QAbstractItemModel?  Shouldn't `m` be showing me additional properties?

Is my understanding so far off as to make this a pointless question and I should run back for the safe hills of C#, Java, and Python where I belong ? Or this is an IDE-issue and using something else (Eclipse? KDevelop? QT Creator Open Source?) would yield better results?

I did follow the [CLion Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#debug-renderers) for setting up debug renderers. I used Lekensteyn's qt5printers, which at least allowed some basic types like QString to have a pretty view. But it seems like only a handful of the data types are accessible.

## Background

I'm typically a C#, Java, and Python developer, but came across a bug in a tool I use that is C++/QT5 based. I'd like to build a bit more knowledge of real C++ development and thought this might be a good opportunity to dive in and see what I can figure out. I'm realizing I have possibly been spoiled by these languages and am a little lost on something that seems basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory management mechanism of C++ is quite different from those language you mentioned. For the `m` you provide is a pointer to `c`, so the value `0x1aa7120` is correct. It indicates the address in memory the pointer point to.

If you want to see member variables or functions of `m`, then use `->` operator, like `m->checkIndex()`. Here is the Qt official documentation for you: [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html) and [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html).

By the way, if you are new to C++ and Qt, I would suggest to use Qt Creator as your IDE, which provides templates and documentations you can refer to.